# Unit testing JSON Swift

Tags: json, swift, unit-testing, swift2

I am working on an iOS application written in Swift which parse a lot of  JSON files.
The JSON structures are sophisticated and I would to test them before to map JSON to object.

For example test if the key 'users' exists and for each user the structure('name', 'first', 'last').

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "name": {
        "first": "emmi",
        "last": "wiita"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "first": "erdi",
        "last": "nielen"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": {
        "first": "daniel",
        "last": "beck"
      }
    }
 ]
}
```

Are there any good way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your post @Felipe Plets. I found a good way to test JSON file.

I have implemented an enum ErrorType(Exception):

```
/**
 Enumeration describing possible errors that occur while parsing 
 a message from JSON file.
*/
enum ReceiverError: ErrorType {
    /**
     Error trigge when the key is missed or the type.
     - Parameter key: Key missed.
    */
    case MissingKeyOrType(key: String)
}
```

then I can test all the JSON file like this:

```
func isValidJSON(message: [String: AnyObject]) -> throws {
    guard let sosId = message["id"] as? String 
        else { throw ReceiverError.MissingKeyOrType(key: "sos - id") }
    guard let text = message["text"] as? String 
        else { throw ReceiverError.MissingKeyOrType(key: "text")
}

let json = ... Get JSON

do {
   try isValidJSON(json)
} catch CustomReceiver.ReceiverError.MissingKeyOrType(let key) {
   print("Error: Missing key or type [key: \(key)].")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to accomplish that is really opening the JSON file and testing each property.

A good news is that since Swift 2.0 you can use guard to test if you can assign a valid value to a var or let, so you can create a function as follows:

```
func isValidJSON(data: NSData) -> Bool {
    json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .AllowFragments)

    // if "users" exists on the JSON
    // AND we can cast it to an array of dictionaries
    guard let users = json["users"] as [[String: AnyObject]] else {
      return false
    }

    for user in users {
        guard let name = user["name"] as [[String: AnyObject]]
            firstName = name["first"] as String,
            lastName = name["last"] as String else {
                return false
        }
    }

    // valid JSON
    return true
}
```

A best practice would be also to implement the use of Exceptions instead returning false in each guard statement.